# Raven DB JsonSerializationException Could not load assembly

Tags: c#, json.net, ravendb

When I try to retrieve a document containing a list of entities whose types are found in a dynamically loaded DLL, I get a `JSONSerialisation` exception, which states that it cannot find the type in the dynamically loaded DLL: `Could not load assembly 'Sandbox_One'`

I am using RavenDB (build 2681) to store entities that are created using [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx), although I don't think that is an issue here. Each of the entities inherit a non-dynamic interface `IEntity`. The Raven Session is being created either side of a .NET MVC 4 Action (as per the [Raven example](http://ravendb.net/kb/3/using-ravendb-in-an-asp-net-mvc-website)) and I am able to save the dynamic entity into a list of `IEntity`.

When I try to load the list of entities back out of the document, I get the serialisation error. At the moment, I only have a single instance (Blue Eyes) of a single entity type (Customer).

## Observations

- In the database, the entity looks exactly as I would expect:

```
{
  "Entities": [
    {
      "$type": "Prometheus.Dynamic.Sandbox_One.Customer, Sandbox_One",
      "Name": "Customer",
      "Eye_colour": "Blue",
      "Age": 9.0,
      "Id": "b0937393-b1bf-4bcb-97d7-1aea7a96e881"
    }
  ]
}
```

- At the point of Loading the entity, I check the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain` for the loaded assemblies and `Prometheus.Dynamic.Sandbox_One` with the `Customer` type is there.
- The `Realm` object has a reference to the dynamically loaded Assembly and I am able to reflect types from it like so:

  `var customer = Activator.CreateInstance(realm.Assembly.GetTypes().First());`
- The Assembly is loaded inside the MVC action, after the RavenDB session was started. Would that make a difference? I imagine not as I expect the JSON.net serializer is looking in the `AppDomain`.

---

## Code and Exception

Full stack trace of the Exception:

```
[JsonSerializationException: Could not load assembly 'Sandbox_One'.]
   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultSerializationBinder.GetTypeFromTypeNameKey(TypeNameKey typeNameKey) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\DefaultSerializationBinder.cs:69
   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ThreadSafeStore`2.AddValue(TKey key) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Utilities\ThreadSafeStore.cs:62
   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultSerializationBinder.BindToType(String assemblyName, String typeName) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\DefaultSerializationBinder.cs:119
   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadSpecialProperties(JsonReader reader, Type& objectType, JsonContract& contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue, Object& newValue, String& id) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:473

[JsonSerializationException: Error resolving type specified in JSON 'Prometheus.Dynamic.Sandbox_One.Customer, Sandbox_One'. Path 'Entities[0].$type'.]
   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadSpecialProperties(JsonReader reader, Type& objectType, JsonContract& contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue, Object& newValue, String& id) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:526
   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:344
   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:238
   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IWrappedCollection wrappedList, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:1132
   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:572
   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:240
   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:692
   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:1593

[JsonSerializationException: Could not read value for property: Entities]
   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:1602
   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:368
   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:238
   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:164
   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonSerializer.cs:565
   Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.ConvertToEntity(Type entityType, String id, RavenJObject documentFound, RavenJObject metadata) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.cs:457
   Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.TrackEntity(Type entityType, String key, RavenJObject document, RavenJObject metadata, Boolean noTracking) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.cs:404
   Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.TrackEntity(Type entityType, JsonDocument documentFound) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.cs:388
   Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.TrackEntity(JsonDocument documentFound) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.cs:343
   Raven.Client.Document.SessionOperations.LoadOperation.Complete() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\SessionOperations\LoadOperation.cs:61
   Raven.Client.Document.DocumentSession.Load(String id) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\DocumentSession.cs:230
   Prometheus.Core.DomainServices.DataManager.GetDataForRealm(IDocumentSession session, Realm realm) in c:\TeamProjectsCloud\Prometheus\Prometheus.Core\DomainServices\DataManager.cs:48
   Prometheus.Portal.Controllers.DataController.Index(String entityName) in c:\TeamProjectsCloud\Prometheus\Prometheus.Portal\Controllers\DataController.cs:23
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +192
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +274
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass39.b__33() +120
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass4f.b__49() +452
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass37.b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass2a.b__20() +33
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +240
   System.Web.Mvc.c__DisplayClass1d.b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.c__DisplayClass8.b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

The controller (I've bolded the call where the Entities are loaded):
NB `RavenSession` is inherited from a base controller exactly as in the [MVC site example](http://ravendb.net/kb/3/using-ravendb-in-an-asp-net-mvc-website)

```
public ActionResult Index(string entityName)
{
     var viewModel = new DataViewModel();
     var realm = realmManager.GetRealm(RavenSession, viewModel.SelectedRealm);
     viewModel.Entities = realmManager.GetEntities(realm);
     viewModel.CurrentEntity = viewModel.Entities.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == entityName);
     viewModel.Data = dataManager.GetDataForRealm(RavenSession, realm); // Call to loading method

     return View(viewModel);
}
```

The Load call that is throwing the exception:

```
    public List<IEntity> GetDataForRealm(IDocumentSession session, Realm realm)
    {
        var realmData = session.Load<RealmData>(realm.RealmDataId); // Exception thrown
        return realmData.Entities;
    }
```

The Realm Data class:

```
public class RealmData
{
    public RealmData()
    {
        Entities = new List<IEntity>();
    }
    public List<IEntity> Entities { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to implement an `AssemblyResolve` event handler on the App Domain.

The `GetDataForRealm` method becomes:

```
public List<IEntity> GetDataForRealm(IDocumentSession session, Realm realm)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (s, a) => MyResolveEventHandler(s, a, realm.Assembly);

        var realmData = session.Load<RealmData>(realm.RealmDataId);
        return realmData.Entities;
    }
```

The event handler looks like this:

```
private Assembly MyResolveEventHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args, Assembly assembly)
    {
        if (assembly.GetName().Name == args.Name)
        {
            return assembly;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**What I believe was happening:**

When the JSON.Net deserializer was reflecting out the dynamic type, it could not find the Assembly in the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain`. The handler is called when the `AppDomain` cannot find the assembly by name. My assembly was in the AppDomain (as I used Assembly.Load) but it could not be found.

**Note:**
I extended `MyResolveEventHandler` with an extra parameter because I already had the Assembly I needed. If you don't have the Assembly in memory (but know where it is) then you can load it inside `MyResovleEventHandler`.

## Update

You may find that you have problems assigning data to these resultant objects later. This is because passing the Entity through the `AppDomain` does not mean that it changes the Domain of the object. Instead, it just hands a reference. Instead, I found that it was easier to get RavenDB to create the objects in the correct (temporary) Domain in the first place using a Custom JSON Converter that has the dynamic assembly in a member. [See that solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900283/how-do-i-use-a-custom-json-net-converter-in-ravendb-to-deserialize-into-types-fr).